# Parse and Split text from XML tag

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

Im receiving an XML RSS feed. One of the tags look like this:

```
<georss:point>55.0794503724671 -3.31266344234773</georss:point>
```

I need a simple way to extract these two lat and long values into seperate values [as part of my other XML reading foreach loop..].

EDIT:

I am now trying:

```
private void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
     var document = XDocument.Load(e.Result);

        if (document.Root == null)
            return;

        var georss = XNamespace.Get("http://www.georss.org/georss");

        var events = from ev in document.Descendants("item")

   //how can I define the below for the Value.split?
 //var points = from point in parentElement.Elements(geoRssNs + "point") 


     let values = ev.Value.Split(' ')  

             select new              
           {
             Latitude = double.Parse(values[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
             Longitude = double.Parse(values[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 

             Title = (ev.Element("title").Value),
             Description = (ev.Element("description").Value),
             PubDate = (ev.Element("pubDate").Value),
           }; 


             //Add pushpin here
```

}
        }

Comment: Why would you want to do this when the values in geo:Point are the same values encoded inot georss:Point???

Comment: Hi Anthony, the particular xml document im reading in this case does not have the geo:point values with seperate lat/long like the coded example above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It strikes me that this isn't really XML - it's just normal string handling. For example, it could be something like this:

```
XNamespace geoRssNs = "http://whatever/url/it/is";

var points = from point in parentElement.Elements(geoRssNs + "point")
             let values = point.Value.Split(' ')
             select new
             {
               Latitude = double.Parse(values[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
               Longitude = double.Parse(values[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
             };
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a play with this tonight.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for the answer. Im doing some playing now.

Comment: Hi Jon, Ive been having a play with this. One issue is that it doesnt like the 'Values' word. The error is: Error 1 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'Values' and no extension method 'Values' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\QuakeML\MainPage.xaml.cs 57 45 QuakeML

Comment: @Dan: Sorry, that should just have been Value instead of Values.

Comment: Hi Jon sorry to bother you but im having problems due to my lack of knowledge here. This is how ive set up the code you suggested.. but I get the error saying parentElelemnt does not exsist in current context?..... var events = from ev in parentElement.Elements(georss + "point") let value = ev.Value.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 2)

Comment: @Dan: Well you need to provide the XML... `parentElement` is assumed to be an `XElement` which is the parent of the `point` elements.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your answers so far. The split auguments are throwing up errors, and cant quite find where the problem lies. I have edited my original post to reflect my current status. Many thanks.

Comment: @Dan: Ah - that overload isn't available in Silverlight. Just use `Value.Split(' ')` and trust that there are only two parts :) (I've edited my answer.)

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for your answer. Ive been trying to work out how to integrate that into my existing XML document reading method, where I am also extracting some other tags, and then passing them to my foreach loop. Ive edited my question above to show my current workings. I understand I need to define where to get the 'Value' from which it is splitting, like your example above. I take it I have to put (georss + "point") to tell values what to split but cant quite work out where to put it once this is in my other code? I owe you a pint Jon!

Comment: You should be calling `something.Element(georss + "point")` to get the `point` element, and the Value property will fetch the contents of that element as a string. You could potentially do this in a `let` clause to avoid having to fetch and split twice, or just use the same expression twice but fetch different values from the array, if you don't mind the inefficiency too much :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this Jon, Ive pretty much got what I wanted to do now, I just have one snag where it bombs out if the (georss + "point") tag does not exsist in the XML items as some dont. So I will try and work out what to do or post up a new question I think. Thanks again. Dan

Answer (score 2):

how about something like this

```
XDocument.Load(e.Result)
    .Descendants("item")
    .Descendants("georss:point")
    .Select(v => v.Value.Split(' '))
    .Select(ll => new GeoCoordinate{Longitude = ll[0], Latitude = ll[1]})
    .Select(g => new Pushpin{ 
        Location = g, 
        Background = (Brush)MediaTypeNames
                    .Application
                    .Current
                    .Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]})
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(p => QuakeLayer.AddChild(p, p.Location));
```

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for your answer. Could you be knid enough to explain how this is working, speicfically the 4/5th line selecting the two values?

Comment: firstly your splitting the text in the value of georss:point by the space character, to get the two strings, then you are using them in the next line to create a new GeoCoordinate object

Comment: I don't believe you can build a GeoCoordinate from strings... you need to parse them.

Comment: Its close but a) as Jon says you will need to parse each value into a double and b) the Pushpin takes a `Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Location` type for its `Location` property not a GeoCoordinate.